# Win32 Bitmap on menuItem and checkmark

Tags: winapi

Is it possible to checkmark a menuitem showing a bitmap for an app running on Windows 7 (visual styles active)?. I only get a blue rectangle surrounding the place where the checkmark should be:
[image: Demo image].

The code i'm using to configure the menuitem is:

```
MENUITEMINFO mii = { 0 }; //all members null
mii.cbSize = sizeof(MENUITEMINFO);
mii.fMask = MIIM_TYPE | MIIM_STATE;
mii.fType = MFT_BITMAP;
mii.fState = MFS_CHECKED;
mii.dwTypeData = (LPSTR)bmp; //the bitmap shown in the menuItem
SetMenuItemInfo(hmenu, itemID, FALSE, &mii);
```

Comment: Did you call DrawMenuBar "https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms647633(v=vs.85).aspx" after SetMenuItemInfo? You should also check for errors (i.e. if SetMenuItemInfo returns zero you should call GetLastError to retrieve the error code).

Comment: The documentation for [MENUITEMINFO](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms647578.aspx) isn't very clear, but I believe you need to add the `MIIM_CHECKMARKS` flag, and leave the *hbmpChecked* member set to `NULL` (to use the default bitmap).

Comment: I tried your suggestions and i get 1 for return value of SetMenuItemInfo, DrawMenuBar seems to have no effect calling it afterwards and MIIM_CHECKMARS neither. I hope not being the only person who tried to checkmark a menuitem showing a bitmap instead of text ;-)